# Get content from a text file to String (Android) (FileNotFound) (Java)

Tags: java, android, filenotfoundexception

I want to get the text from a text file I have in my project (android studio) and make that text to a string. I am currently having trouble getting the correct path or something. I'm using two methods I found here on Stackoverflow to get the textfiles to Strings. These are the methods:

```
public static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line).append("\n");
    }
    reader.close();
    return sb.toString();
}

public static String getStringFromFile (String filePath) throws Exception {
    File fl = new File(filePath);
    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(fl);
    String ret = convertStreamToString(fin);
    //Make sure you close all streams.
    fin.close();
    return ret;
}
```

And I'm calling the methods like this, and I have tried all kinds of pathing but none seems to work:

```
Log.i("er0r", Solve.getStringFromFile("\\tables\\lowerLayer\\cross\\whiteRed.txt"));
```

This is just an attempt to print the content of the textfile. I get the following error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: .\tables\lowerLayer\cross\whiteRed.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

This is how I have ordered my packages:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JRQz.jpg

How can i fix this? Thanks

EDIT:

```
public String LoadData(String inFile) {
    String str = "";
    try{
        StringBuilder buf=new StringBuilder();
        InputStream json=getAssets().open(inFile);
        BufferedReader in=
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(json, "UTF-8"));
        while ((str=in.readLine()) != null) {
            buf.append(str);
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("er0r", e.toString());
    }
    return str;
}
```

Tried this with inFile = "assets\whiteRed.txt"
Got me this error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: assets\whiteRed.txt

ADDITIONAL CODE:
Constructor of the class that's calling the LoadData method

```
public class Solve {

private Context context;
//constructor

public Solve(Context context){
    this.context = context;
}
```

Comment: `("\\tables\\lowerLayer\\cross\\whiteRed.txt"`. That is a non existing impossible file system path. No wonder that the file can not be found. How did you come up with that path? Where is your txt file in reality?

Comment: In the picture I linked u can see how it's structured. I'm pretty new to this, what is the correct path?
Thanks

Comment: That is in Android Studio. Why do you think they will be in your app when your phone is out of town for instance?

Comment: Well, I though all such files would get into the apk or something. If it doesn't, how do I get the files into the phone?
Thanks

Comment: `Tried this with inFile = "assets\whiteRed.txt"`. No. Try  with `inFile = "whiteRed.txt";`

Comment: That got me this error instead: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message. And my text file is not empty, by the way.

Comment: There is no pintln() in your code. So where are you talking about?

Comment: Im trying to print out the content of the file like this;

Log.i("er0r", LoadData("whiteRed.txt"));

Comment: Have a look at that code where you return variable str after the last read which delivers null. Add `return buf.toString();` as last line in the try block. You were not using the string builder! Were you?

Comment: `buf.append(str);` That should be `buf.append(str+"\n");`.

Comment: Now it's working! Thanks a lot. It's hard to diagnose problems when you really don't have any idea about what you're doing.
I owe you.

Comment: @greenapps I suppose the method I posted can't be static since the getAssets is non-static? And do I need to have this method in an activity class?

Comment: You need a Context as CommonsWare already told you. Yes. You can make it a static function. LoadData(Context contex, String fileName)  and then context.getAssets()...

Comment: I think I need the method to be static. Buy why does the context has to be a parameter, can't it be constant? I dont understand what it is or why it's useful. Could you please give me an example of what to put before .getAssets()

Comment: That i already told you! Please read!

Comment: Where do you call the function from? CommonsWare asked you that already too.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm stupid, but I can't help it, and I can't see where you wrote that. One answer has been deleted. But I'm calling that method from another java class. An ordinary java class that has nothng to do with android at all.

Comment: Repeat: `and then context.getAssets()... `.

Comment: Yes, I can add that as a parameter if you like. But then I have no idea about what to send as a parameter when I'm calling the method.

Comment: Can you add a constructor to that java class with a Context parameter? Or just add a Context parameter to the constructor?

Comment: And where do you create that java class?

Comment: I have no constructor on the class I wish to call the method from. It's just a class that contains methods. Should I make one anyway?

Comment: I have all classes in the same directory.

Comment: Add such a constructor and save the Context variable in a private member of the class. You can then use it to call loadData. You did not answer from where you instantiated the class.

Comment: I'm not sure what u mean with instantiate the class. I just created a class in the same directory as the other classes. I'm not creating objects of ths class. But I can try to make a constructor in it.

Comment: If you have a class then you have a java file somewhere in Android Studio. But you will use that class somewhere in your code. How? If the methods are not static you have to instantiate a class object/variable before using a method. FROM WHERE ARE YOU CALLING THOSE METHODS?

Comment: I added the constructor in my post. My class has a lot of static methods which are callad from other classes and itself. And almost all the methods in the class calls the LoadData method.

Comment: Static methods cannot use that Context parameter.

Comment: `which are callad from other classes `. You will never come to the point will you!? From activities?

Comment: I don't know how to respond to that, since I dont know anything about Context. But doesn't this seem a bit too advanced in order for me to just read some text from a text file?

Comment: Well you already checked and confirmed that it worked. So where did you do that?

Comment: The class is called from the activity, yes.

Comment: I called the method from the class that it's in (the activity class). But when I try to call the method from the other class I get problems with static things.

Comment: If you use static methods of your class then give every method that uses loadData an extra Context parameter. And call the method from an activity like MyClass.myMethod(this, other parameters);

Comment: So I must call the LoadData method from an activity? I want to call it from a normal class. Or did I get you wrong?

Comment: Maybe you can do away with all those context parameters and use something like getApplicationContex().getAssets()... Or getBaseContext().getAssets()... Please try them all.

Comment: Yes you got me wrong. You will call loadData from your methods you said. I am just telling you how you can 'forward' a context to it using an extra Context parameter.

Comment: When I tried to use getApplicationContex().getAssets() and the other one, I get Non-static method "getApplicationContext" cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: Well you have tried and now you know. Or make loadData non static or continue with the extra parameters.

Comment: I have no problem with using an extra parameter. I just don't know what that parameter should be. I tried to call the method with the parameter getApplicationContext() but that didnt work of course. What should I send as paramater?

Comment: That i already exactly told you!

Comment: Maybe you have, but I don't see where. I created a private Context named context. So, what EXACTLY should I enter as the second parameter?

Comment: Repeat: `And call the method from an activity like MyClass.myMethod(this, other parameters)`.

Comment: Show how you call such a static method from an activity.

Comment: @greenapps But I don't want to call the method from an activity. I want to call it from a normal class.

Comment: Your own words: `The class is called from the activity, yes. `.

Comment: You might know that there's a difference between a class and a method. The method LoadData is in an activity. But I want to call it from a class which is not an activity.

Comment: Please don't teach me. I think i already said all. Just combine the things.

Comment: It sounds like you don't know.

Comment: What should I enter as context parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If at design time, in Android Studio, you want to supply files which your app can read at run time then put them in the assets folder of your Android Studio project.

Maybe you have to create that assets folder first.

After that your app can read those files from assets using assets manager.

Just google for how to do this exactly. All has been posted here many times.

Comment: I found nothing that's working... I have created an assets directory but I can't get it to work.

Comment: Well post the code you tried in your post. And then tell the difficulties. Start with only one file in assets directory to keep things simple.

Comment: Sorry about that mess.